# Blocking List/Queue while object that matches expression is enqueued

Tags: c#, queue

Based on Marc Gravell's [BlockingQueue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/530228/1959238) I wanted to know if there is a way to wait for an object that meets an expression. I have coded a method 'TryDequeueWhere' 
I am not sure if there is something that I have not take into account, or if there is gap in my code...

```
    public class BlockingQueue<T> 
    {

        /// <summary>   The queue based on a list, to extract from position and remove at position. </summary>
        private readonly List<QueueObject<T>> queue = new List<QueueObject<T>>();
        // A Dictionary with expressions that, if matches, should be signalized  
        private IDictionary<string, Func<T, bool>> _expressionList = new Dictionary<string, Func<T, bool>>();

        private class QueueObject<T>
        {
            /// <summary>   Constructor. </summary>
            /// <param name="timeStamp">    The time stamp when the object is enqueued. </param>
            /// <param name="queuedObject"> The queued object. </param>
            public QueueObject(DateTime timeStamp, T queuedObject)
            {
                TimeStamp = timeStamp;
                QueuedObject = queuedObject;
            }


            /// <summary>   Gets or sets the queued object. </summary>
            /// <value> The queued object. </value>
            public T QueuedObject { get; set; }


            /// <summary>   Gets or sets timestamp, when the object was enqueued. </summary>
            /// <value> The time stamp. </value>
            public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

        }


      public void Enqueue(T item)
      {
         lock (queue)
         {
            // Add an object with current time to the queue
            queue.Add(new QueueObject<T>(DateTime.Now, item));

            // if an object is enqueued that matches an expression that was 
            // registered with the TryDequeueWhere method, 
            // the expression is signalized and all waiting threads will be notified
            lock (_expressionList)
            {
               foreach (var expression in _expressionList)
               {
                  if (queue.Select(q => q.QueuedObject).Where(expression.Value).Any())
                  {
                     lock (expression.Value)
                     {
                        Monitor.PulseAll(expression.Value);   
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
            if (queue.Count == 1)
            {
               // wake up any blocked dequeue
               Monitor.PulseAll(queue);
            }
         }
      }
      /// <summary>   Try dequeue an object that matches the passed expression. </summary>
      /// <param name="expression">   The expression that an object has to match. </param>
      /// <param name="value">        [out] The resulting object. </param>
      /// <param name="waitTimeInMs"> (Optional)  The time in ms to wait for the item to be returned. </param>
      /// <returns>   An object that matches the passed expression. </returns>
      public bool TryDequeueWhere(Func<T, bool> expression, out T value, int? waitTimeInMs = null)
      {
         lock (_expressionList)
         {
            // if already another thread waits on an object with this expression return false.
            if (_expressionList.ContainsKey(expression.ToString()))
            {
               value = default(T);
               return false;
            }
         }
         try
         {
            // Register an expression to mark for the Enqueue method that it should signalize that the object is enqueued
            lock (_expressionList)
            {
               _expressionList.Add(expression.ToString(), expression);
            }
            // lock the expression object for exclusive access
            lock (expression)
            {
               if (!queue.Select(q => q.QueuedObject).Any(expression))
               {
                   // if there is a timeout to wait, call Monitor.Wait() and 
                   // wait while the object that matches the expression is enqueued.
                   if (waitTimeInMs != null)
                   {
                      if (!Monitor.Wait(expression, waitTimeInMs.Value))
                      {
                         value = default(T);
                          return false;
                      }
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       Monitor.Wait(expression);
                   }
               }
               try
               {
                  lock (queue)
                  {
                     // select the object by the passed expression
                     var queuedObjects = queue.Select(q => q.QueuedObject).ToList();
                     // Convert the expression to a predicate to get the index of the item
                     Predicate<T> pred = expression.Invoke;
                     int indexOfQueuedObject = queuedObjects.FindIndex(pred);
                     // if item is found, get it and remove it from the list
                     if (indexOfQueuedObject >= 0)
                     {
                        value = queuedObjects.FirstOrDefault(expression);
                        queue.RemoveAt(indexOfQueuedObject);
                        return true;
                     }
                  }
               }
               catch (Exception)
               {
                  value = default(T);
                  return false;
               }
            }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {

         }
         finally
         {
            // remove the expression from the list, because it is not needed anymore
            lock (_expressionList)
            {
               _expressionList.Remove(expression.ToString());
            }
         }
         value = default(T);
         return false;
      }

}
```

**Update:** 
I am not sure but perhaps it is better to explain, why I would need such function.
Let's say you have a socket connection and send data to a server/client. You send them with a specific Sync-ID or something that is unique to identify the message. Now you are waiting for the response. So you can register, that if a message with a specific identification or criteria arrives, you should be notified. And because you don't want to poll and maybe wait only a specific time, you could use such method.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could you name a use case where such a queue would be useful?

Comment: This code contains a few compile errors (not implementing `IDisposable`, `_queueSize` not existing), so it looks like you forgot to include some parts in your post.

Comment: A socket communication where you are waiting for a received object with a certain sync id

Comment: The missing parts are not really important for the functionality. I will remove them to not making things complicated..

Comment: If the missing parts are not important for the functionality why do you have them at all? Why did you have to remove them? If the queue works without them, what is the point of writing the code that you now removed?

Comment: The point is, that this is not the whole class, it is part of it, so that the code is reduced to the base functionality I wanted to get. If I put in the whole class it would perhaps be not so clear..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Deadlocks

- There's a deadlock: `Enqueue` obtains a lock on `queue` and then on `expression.Value`, while `TryDequeueWhere` locks on `expression` and then on `queue`. If you call both methods simultaneously, they both end up holding a lock and waiting for the other's lock to become available.
- There's another problem: expressions are passed in as arguments, so you can't guarantee that calling code isn't locking (or pulsing) on them. This can also lead to deadlocks and other sorts of problems.

Try to always obtain locks in a fixed order, and only lock on objects that you have exclusive access to.

### Design issue

- Why does `TryDequeueWhere` not allow multiple threads to use the same predicate (and why isn't that documented)? This prevents this queue from being used with multiple workers.
- If you do want to prevent reuse of the same predicate, then `expression.ToString()` does not do what you think it does. Unless a class overrides it it returns the full type name, not some kind of unique identifier, so in practice only one dequeue operation can be active at the same time.
- What exactly does it mean for two predicates to be the same? The same method? The same closure instance? Or different methods that both produce the same result? What if you have to predicates: one that matches blue and red, and another that matches green and red, and you add a red item?

I think you overlooked something in the code you linked to. Your dequeue operation assumes that, as soon as `Monitor.Wait` returns, there will be a matching item available. Enqueue wakes up every matching dequeue operation, but only one of them can fetch the item... Marc's code doesn't make such assumptions: it places `while (!canContinueWithWork)` loops around `Monitor.Wait` calls. This causes operations to continue waiting if they can't proceed (for example, because another operation 'got there first').

### Other improvements

- `Enqueue` only needs to check the newly added item against pending dequeue predicates - otherwise those dequeue operations would have finished already.
- `QueueObject<T>` should probably not be mutable. Immutable objects are generally easier to reason about, especially when dealing with concurrency.
- `predicate` would be a more accurate name here than `expression`.
- `foreach (var expression in _expressionList)` - here, `expression` is a `KeyValuePair` object, not a predicate, so the name is somewhat confusing here. Just iterate over `_expressionList.Values` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the very good and detailed suggestions! I rethought my first idea and rebuild my code...

Answer (score 1):

Based on Pieter's suggestions I rethought my first idea and made it a little bit more simple. I think the idea with blocking the expression is not save and generic enough. Now if an object is queued the TryDequeueWhere method is notified and if the object that matches the expression is not found, it waits until the next Pulse or the time is elapsed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

public class BlockingQueue<T>: IDisposable
{

    /// <summary>   The queue based on a list, to extract from position and remove at position. </summary>
    private readonly List<QueueObject<T>> queue = new List<QueueObject<T>>();
    private bool _closing;


    private class QueueObject<T>
    {
        //// <summary>   Constructor. </summary>
        /// <param name="timeStamp">    The time stamp when the object is enqueued. </param>
        /// <param name="queuedObject"> The queued object. </param>
        public QueueObject(DateTime timeStamp, T queuedObject)
        {
            TimeStamp = timeStamp;
            QueuedObject = queuedObject;
        }

        /// <summary>   Gets or sets the queued object. </summary>
        /// <value> The queued object. </value>
        public T QueuedObject { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>   Gets or sets timestamp, when the object was enqueued. </summary>
        /// <value> The time stamp. </value>
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; private set; }
    }


    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        lock (queue)
        {
            // Add an object with current time to the queue
            queue.Add(new QueueObject<T>(DateTime.Now, item));


            if (queue.Count >= 1)
            {
                // wake up any blocked dequeue
                Monitor.PulseAll(queue);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>   Try dequeue an object that matches the passed expression. </summary>
    /// <param name="expression">   The expression that an object has to match. </param>
    /// <param name="value">        [out] The resulting object. </param>
    /// <param name="waitTimeInMs"> (Optional)  The time in ms to wait for the item to be returned. </param>
    /// <returns>   An object that matches the passed expression. </returns>
    public bool TryDequeueWhere(Func<T, bool> expression, out T value, int? waitTimeInMs = null)
    {
        // Save the current time to later calculate a new timeout, if an object is enqueued and does not match the expression.
        DateTime dequeueTime = DateTime.Now;
        lock (queue)
        {
            while (!_closing)
            {
                if (waitTimeInMs == null)
                {
                    while (queue.Count == 0)
                    {
                        if (_closing)
                        {
                            value = default(T);
                            return false;
                        }
                        Monitor.Wait(queue);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Releases the lock on queue and blocks the current thread until it reacquires the lock. 
                    // If the specified time-out interval elapses, the thread enters the ready queue.
                    if (!Monitor.Wait(queue, waitTimeInMs.Value))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        // select the object by the passed expression
                        var queuedObjects = queue.Select(q => q.QueuedObject).ToList();
                        // Convert the expression to a predicate to get the index of the item
                        Predicate<T> pred = expression.Invoke;
                        int indexOfQueuedObject = queuedObjects.FindIndex(pred);
                        // if item is found, get it and remove it from the list
                        if (indexOfQueuedObject >= 0)
                        {
                            value = queuedObjects.FirstOrDefault(expression);
                            queue.RemoveAt(indexOfQueuedObject);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    // If item was not found, calculate the remaining time and try again if time is not elapsed.
                    var elapsedTime = (DateTime.Now - dequeueTime).TotalMilliseconds;
                    if ((int) elapsedTime >= waitTimeInMs.Value)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    waitTimeInMs = waitTimeInMs.Value - (int) elapsedTime;
                }
            }
        }
        value = default(T);
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary> Close the queue and let finish all waiting threads. </summary>
    public void Close()
    {
        lock (queue)
        {
            _closing = true;
            Monitor.PulseAll(queue);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged
    /// resources.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Close();
    }

}
```